# How can I send a HTTP Post from a C# Asp.Net method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, unirest

I would like to query a dictionary API from my C# method. Here's the specification for what is needed:

```
POST /DictService/DictService.asmx/DefineInDict HTTP/1.1
Host: services.aonaware.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

dictId=string&word=string
```

Here's an example of what is returned but right now I don't get anything returned with my way of doing it using Unrest:  http://unirest.io/net.html

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WordDefinition xmlns="http://services.aonaware.com/webservices/">
  <Word>string</Word>
  <Definitions>
    <Definition>
      <Word>string</Word>
      <Dictionary>
        <Id>string</Id>
        <Name>string</Name>
      </Dictionary>
      <WordDefinition>string</WordDefinition>
    </Definition>
    <Definition>
      <Word>string</Word>
      <Dictionary>
        <Id>string</Id>
        <Name>string</Name>
      </Dictionary>
      <WordDefinition>string</WordDefinition>
    </Definition>
  </Definitions>
</WordDefinition>
```

Here's what I tried so far:

```
  HttpResponse<string> jsonResponse = Unirest.post("http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx/DefineInDict")
                .header("Accept", "application/xml")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .field("dictId", "wn")
                .field("word", "abandon")
                .asJson<string>();
```

Always I am getting the error:

> 406 - Client browser does not accept the MIME type of the requested
>   page.

Can someone help and suggest how I can send this post request. Maybe there's something easier than using Unirest. I am open to any simple C# solution

Comment: Since that´s a ASMX service, it would be faster if you added a reference to it.

If not, just do a HttpWebRequest.

If still want to use Unirest, I havent tried it before, just try to change the ContentType.

Comment: @JuanCarlos - can you give me an example and some more details. I am open to using anything that works :-)

Comment: Your response Content-Type is text-xml but you accept only application-xml. Also, of course asJson is going to fail.

Comment: @Alan https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/21/help-me-how-do-i-connect-to-an-asmx-web-service/

Answer (score 1):

Since it is asmx, you can generate WSDL.

[image]

[image]

It will generate the following files inside `Service References` folder.

[image]

Then you can call it as

[image]

### HelloWorld.asmx.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for HelloWorld
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class HelloWorld : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string GetHelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

***FYI:*** asmx is a very old technology which has been deprecated. If this is a new application, you might consider looking for REST.